# Ansible Tower - Standard Output of jobs

Tags: logging, ansible, ansible-tower

I can view standard output of my jobs in Standard out pane, however where are these logs stored on server and how can I view them?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ansible configuration file, `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`, you can find a line for log path.

```
log_path = /var/log/ansible.log
```

By default, it will be commented. Uncomment it and run your playbook. The logs will be updated in `/var/log/ansible.log`

Tower job output log.

```
eg:
Retrieve Job Stdout  
<http://ansibletowerserver.com>/api/v2/jobs/{id}/stdout/
```

See reference: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/towerapi/api_ref.html#/Jobs

You can call it using `uri` module

Comment: thanks but those logs are ansible logs. I am looking for Tower standout output of jobs on server side.

Comment: You need to use Tower API for that.Updated answer